# How to Show Two Records in One Table?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a procedure like below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE studentpvt2
AS
BEGIN

SELECT 
     TOP 1 StudentName, 
     EC1,
     EC2,
     EC3,
     EC4,
     EC5,
     TotalMarks=EC1+EC2+EC3+EC4+EC5 
 FROM Student pivot
(
SUM (Marks) FOR subject IN ([EC1],[EC2],[EC3],[EC4],[EC5],[TotalMarks])
)
AS pivotTable ORDER  BY TotalMarks DESC

SELECT 
     TOP 1 StudentName,
     EC1,
     EC2,
     EC3,
     EC4,
     EC5,
     TotalMarks=EC1+EC2+EC3+EC4+EC5 
 FROM Student pivot
(
SUM (Marks) FOR subject IN ([EC1],[EC2],[EC3],[EC4],[EC5],[TotalMarks])
)
AS pivotTable ORDER  BY TotalMarks ASC;

END
```

When I execute this the output comes as:

```
studentName EC1 EC2 EC3 EC4 EC5 TotalMarks
  Smita     76  45  67  56  76  320   

studentName EC1 EC2 EC3 EC4 EC5 TotalMarks
  Rajesh    34  56  12  45  23  170
```

I want them to show the the two records in a single table, so please help me how to get that output. This is my first question so please excuse me if anything wrong.

The original table is:

`StudentID StudentName Subject Marks
1   Savita  EC1 50
1   Savita  EC2 55
1   Savita  EC3 45
1   Savita  EC4 34
1   Savita  EC5 23
2   Rajesh  EC1 34
2   Rajesh  EC2 56
2   Rajesh  EC3 12
2   Rajesh  EC4 45
2   Rajesh  EC5 23
3   Smita   EC1 76
3   Smita   EC2 45
3   Smita   EC3 67
3   Smita   EC4 56
3   Smita   EC5 76
4   Rahul   EC1 66
4   Rahul   EC2 34
4   Rahul   EC3 22
4   Rahul   EC4 18
4   Rahul   EC5 33`

Comment: Use the Union to get data in single set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE studentpvt2
AS
BEGIN

SELECT * FROM (SELECT 
     TOP 1 StudentName, 
     EC1,
     EC2,
     EC3,
     EC4,
     EC5,
     TotalMarks=EC1+EC2+EC3+EC4+EC5 
 FROM Student pivot
(
SUM (Marks) FOR subject IN ([EC1],[EC2],[EC3],[EC4],[EC5],[TotalMarks])
)
AS pivotTable order by [TotalMarks])A


UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM (SELECT 
     TOP 1 StudentName, 
     EC1,
     EC2,
     EC3,
     EC4,
     EC5,
     TotalMarks=EC1+EC2+EC3+EC4+EC5 
 FROM Student pivot(
SUM (Marks) FOR subject IN ([EC1],[EC2],[EC3],[EC4],[EC5],[TotalMarks])
)
AS pivotTable order by [TotalMarks] DESC)B

END
```

Comment: sir this proc gives an output for "Rahul" two times. but i need the two records with highest totalmarks and lowest total marks. so i add a few changes "AS pivotTable order by TotalMarks desc  )A
ORDER BY TotalMarks ;" then it gives the record for Rahul and smita.  But as per my table Rahul has the 2nd lowest Total marks, Rajesh is the lowest one..

Comment: yes sir it worked. But you missed a "("  after second pivot operator and also there is a 'S'. Thank you..

Comment: Sorry @LagnajitPuhan it was a typo!

Comment: hi , can u help me a little more with this topic??

Comment: how to display the same records by adding another column after TotalMarks displaying whether a student gets pass or fail. If a student has less than 30 marks in two subjects then he/she is failed or else pass..

Comment: Use the `CASE` statement. Something like this...`SELECT *, CASE WHEN TotalMarks >= 30 THEN 'Pass' ELSE 'Fail' END AS Result FROM ...... `

Comment: the pass or fail will decide on each subjects not totalmarks. If he/she has less than 30 in two subjects then fail other wise pass. It will display all the records including pass and fail..

Answer (score 1):

Use `UNION` or `UNION ALL`. You should also change your `ORDER BY` to `WHERE` clause to prevent the error. See below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE studentpvt2
AS
BEGIN

SELECT 
     TOP 1 StudentName, 
     EC1,
     EC2,
     EC3,
     EC4,
     EC5,
     TotalMarks=EC1+EC2+EC3+EC4+EC5 
 FROM Student pivot
(
SUM (Marks) FOR subject IN ([EC1],[EC2],[EC3],[EC4],[EC5],[TotalMarks])
)
AS pivotTable WHERE TotalMarks = (
                 SELECT TOP 1 Sum(Marks) s_m
                 FROM   Student 
                 GROUP  BY StudentName
                 ORDER  BY s_m DESC)
UNION ALL
SELECT 
     TOP 1 StudentName,
     EC1,
     EC2,
     EC3,
     EC4,
     EC5,
     TotalMarks=EC1+EC2+EC3+EC4+EC5 
 FROM Student pivot
(
SUM (Marks) FOR subject IN ([EC1],[EC2],[EC3],[EC4],[EC5],[TotalMarks])
)
AS pivotTable WHERE TotalMarks = (
                 SELECT TOP 1 Sum(Marks) s_m
                 FROM   Student 
                 GROUP  BY StudentName
                 ORDER  BY s_m ASC);

END
```

Comment: i tried to do so but is gives an error saying Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'union'.

Comment: Edited my answer. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `Union` between two `pivot` queries use single pivot and filter the max and min total after pivoting

You cannot use `order by` in middle of `Union` or `Union All`

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT StudentName,
               EC1,
               EC2,
               EC3,
               EC4,
               EC5,
               TotalMarks=EC1 + EC2 + EC3 + EC4 + EC5
        FROM   Yourtable
               PIVOT ( Sum(Marks)
                     FOR subject IN([EC1],
                                    [EC2],
                                    [EC3],
                                    [EC4],
                                    [EC5],
                                    [TotalMarks]) ) AS pivotTable) a
WHERE  TotalMarks = (SELECT TOP 1 Sum(Marks) s_m
                     FROM   Yourtable
                     GROUP  BY StudentName
                     ORDER  BY s_m DESC)
        OR TotalMarks = (SELECT TOP 1 Sum(Marks) s_m
                         FROM   Yourtable
                         GROUP  BY StudentName
                         ORDER  BY s_m ASC)
```

Or use `stacked CTE`

```
;WITH min_cte
     AS (SELECT TOP 1 StudentName,
                      EC1,EC2,EC3,EC4,EC5,
                      TotalMarks=EC1 + EC2 + EC3 + EC4 + EC5
         FROM   Yourtable
                PIVOT ( Sum(Marks)
                      FOR subject IN([EC1],
                                     [EC2],
                                     [EC3],
                                     [EC4],
                                     [EC5],
                                     [TotalMarks]) ) AS pivotTable
         ORDER  BY TotalMarks ASC),
     max_cte
     AS (SELECT TOP 1 StudentName,
                      EC1,EC2,EC3,EC4,EC5,
                      TotalMarks=EC1 + EC2 + EC3 + EC4 + EC5
         FROM   Yourtable
                PIVOT ( Sum(Marks)
                      FOR subject IN([EC1],
                                     [EC2],
                                     [EC3],
                                     [EC4],
                                     [EC5],
                                     [TotalMarks]) ) AS pivotTable
         ORDER  BY TotalMarks DESC) SELECT *
FROM   min_cte
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM   max_cte
```